# How to display a div inside colorbox - Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

I want to display a div inside Colorbox plugin, but it is not working as there are many double quotes inside the div element and is causing problems so how can I do it.

Here is my code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('welcomehelloState') != 'shown'){
        function openColorBox(){
                $.colorbox({transition: "fade", top: "2%", width:"67%", height:"17%", html: "<section class="related">
    <p>New Content:-</p>
    <a href="/part-2/index>
        <img src="img/related/Prdha.png" />
        <h3>Art</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="/part-2/index6">
        <img src="img/related/Kavi.png" />
        <h3>Games</h3>
    </a>
    </section>"});
                               }
        setTimeout(openColorBox, 100);
        localStorage.setItem('welcomehelloState','shown')
        };});
</script>
```

As you can see there are many double quotes and the brackets are not syncing.

Comment: just follow the trail of double and single quote..find where they are finishing and then put your div but be careful while putting in, must close the last unfinished quote. btw where you want, after new content heading or games?

Comment: actually the div I was mentioning is the <section> tag

Comment: well you should not give any enter betwen lines as jquery won't take enter so. use this $.colorbox({transition: "fade", top: "2%", width:"67%", height:"17%", html: '<section class="related"><p>New Content:-</p><a href="/part-2/index"><img src="img/related/Prdha.png" /><h3>Art</h3></a><a href="/part-2/index6"><img src="img/related/Kavi.png" /><h3>Games</h3></a></section>'});

Comment: if this comment will solve your issue then let me know so i can post it as answer..ty

Comment: thank you Leo the Lion. It worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you start a string with a double-quote (") and you place an other quote in the string, JS thinks you ended the string. Thats why the quotes which have to be in the string, have to be escaped: `\"`

Example: `var x = "En then he said: \"Hi there\", with a big smile";`

Also, JS does not like linebreaks. you have to escape these too if you need it badly, but the better way is to break the string into multiple strings

Example:

```
var x = "this is" +
"A multiline" + 
"String.";
```

Your code, escaped well, has to be this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('welcomehelloState') != 'shown'){
            function openColorBox(){
                $.colorbox({transition: "fade", top: "2%", width:"67%", height:"17%", html: "<section class=\"related\">" +
                "<p>New Content:-</p>" +
                "<a href=\"/part-2/index\">" +
                        "<img src=\"img/related/Prdha.png\" />" +
                        "<h3>Art</h3>" +
                        "</a>" +
                        "<a href=\"/part-2/index6\">" +
                        "<img src=\"img/related/Kavi.png\" />" +
                        "<h3>Games</h3>" +
                        "</a>" +
                        "</section>"});
            }
            setTimeout(openColorBox, 100);
            localStorage.setItem('welcomehelloState','shown')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery and making html then make sure there is no enter in lines as jquery won't accept this and it will create an syntax error. use your code in this way..

```
$.colorbox({transition: "fade", top: "2%", width:"67%", height:"17%", html: '<section class="related"><p>New Content:-</p><a href="/part-2/index"><img src="img/related/Prdha.png" /><h3>Art</h3></a><a href="/part-2/index6"><img src="img/related/Kavi.png" /><h3>Games</h3></a></section>'});
```

Thank you :)